# Can't return large JSON response using Webflux - it fails with both netty and jetty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, embedded-jetty, reactor-netty

I want to return a large (between 3 and 9 Mb) json body from a webflux endpoint. At this point, I'm simply trying to return it as a `Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>` — bypassing any serialization/deserialization altogether. However, in most cases it returns only part of the actual string. Content-Type is correct, but the bytes sent don't match - often off by a Mb or more, but definitely short a few hundred k.

You'll see below that Content-Type is being set (somewhere lower level) and thus it's not sending it chunked. Since chunked is the default, why is this happening? It happens with either netty or jetty.

When I output the the headers just before sending the ResponseEntity, it shows transfer-encoding: chunked. And yet, the response headers (in curl, chrome, Python requests library) all show the Content-Length and not chunked.

```
// IN CONTROLLER
log.info(response.getHeaders());
return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(findByApplicationId(id), HttpStatus.OK));
```

this will log the following `[transfer-encoding:"chunked"]`

```
// IN TERMINAL WITH CURL
MBP:my-test em$ curl -v localhost:8888/api/thing/0  > /dev/null
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8888 (#0)
> GET /api/thing/0 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8888
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 5198562
<
{ [16308 bytes data]
100 5076k  100 5076k    0     0  16.0M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16.0M
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**Why is Content-Length set above — where did chunked go?**

It is common to see mismatches between the reported Content-Length and the actual received string (which is obviously cut off short)

Here is my POM for completeness:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>bugfix-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>webflux-jsonb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>webflux-jsonb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You should never be setting `Transfer-Encoding` in the response headers, that's for the container to do.

Comment: Please include [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, not just the maven pom.  Your 2 lines is insufficient to render a proper answer.

Comment: Hi Joakim, thank you for the reply. I'm never setting it, but it is already set (as expected) just before sending the response, but it is getting overwritten somewhere lower level with the Content-Length and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Something is setting it, as that header is set as part of the response entering the committed state, which isn't possible in your scenario as you haven't sent the content yet.

Comment: Don't focus on the `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding`, once you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then others can help you.

Comment: That makes sense. Does it help to know that when trying with Jetty specifically, the following is logged during a request?

```Closed while Pending/Unready```

I'll get an example together with non private data to reproduce. Thank you.

Comment: Clearly something is done in the code you have not provided. You need to provide the entire picture if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think this is fixed in Spring 5.1.12.RELEASE or 5.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Confirmed in my demo app that I can get back large responses now where it was cut off before.

---

I have reason to believe this is a bug in Spring 5.1.6/Spring Boot 2.1.5 and up, based on empirical testing. You can assess my findings here:

(Issue submitted to Spring)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24128

(Repository that demonstrates the issue)
https://github.com/opentable/webflux-large-response-spring

Some questions:

- Are you using Jetty server, or a different server (e.g. Reactor Netty)?
- What environment are you running the application in when you are able to reproduce the issue (e.g. local in IDE, in a docker container, etc?)
- Is the response size where the data gets cut off consistent?

Comment: I'm happy to hear there might be a fix in place. The issue was only happening for me on Jetty. I resolved the problem by switching to Netty. I think it was always running in Docker container, failing in both docker-compose and Open Shift. As for the cutoff point, it changed a little from request to request, but would always return at least 75-80% of the payload - anecdotal. Thanks for your feedback!